# Display Date and Time of [PXDBDate] in single grid field

Tags: acumatica

How can I display both the Date and Time of a [PXDBDate] field (such as the CreatedDateTime audit field) in a single grid column?

Setting the `TimeMode` property to True displays only the Time, no longer the date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `DisplayFormat` editor control property and assign the desired .Net Framework [standard date and time format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)

A value of `g` will display both date and time.

[image]

Comment: I was using the Visual Studio form template designer which did not provide this Property but explicitly adding it to the <px:PXGridColumn .. DisplayFormat="g"  /> did format it as desired.

Comment: There's a filter button with funnel icon (highlighted in red in my screenshot). The property is likely not shown when Filter is on (shows only most common properties).

Comment: For the Visual Studio form template they are probably obsolete/deprecated and therefore missing the property.